# Why doesn't import gym work; however, the command pip install gym was done and executed

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have went to the terminal and used,"pip install gym", and it successfully installed gym .  When I go to use the, "import gym," command, I get an error when running the code at that line.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'gym'
```

I have looked at other posts and they all say it should work after ruining,"pip install gym." Although mine successfully installed, it still doesn't work.

Comment: after importing `sys` try `sys.path.append('directory of gym')`

Comment: I would always run pip in the context of my current python `python -m pip install gym`

Comment: @JonSG I tried this; howe er, It wouldn't even install

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that you are using the same version of python that you did `pip install` with. In VS Code, you can select the Python version in the upper right corner. Simply type "python --version" into the console to verify the version. You might want to use Anaconda because someone libraries like Tensorflow only fully-support Anaconda.

Comment: I am using python 3.10.7.  Is there ar special version of gym that I should import?

Comment: You did pip install in one console with one version of python, but then your console is using a different version of python. Just install Anaconda and install it from the Anaconda prompt, then set your Python version to your Anaconda environment.

Comment: I am not using the same version that I used python with.  ICan I just uninstall gym and reinstall when useing the right version>3.11?

Answer (score -1):

if you have pip installed it, there is no way that it will not work. Unless you've installed it to a virtual environment and running your program without it and vice versa. Or you've installed to a different version of python on your system.

Comment: I have the version 3.19.9 installed.  When I run py --version, I get back 3.11.   Everything else is changed on 3.10.9.  Do you know how to make the terminal go back to 3.10.9 instead of 3.11.0?

Comment: [windows]:  go to search find "edit the system environment variables" then go to "environment variable". in **user variable for --- ** click on path and add two new entries. make those entries at the top. in first entry write **path to your python 3.10.9** and in second write **path to python 3.10.9\Scripts**. if you have opened CMD close it and open new one.